# "I did not know but that [...]"

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning

What does it mean? Is it regular English or Hemingway English?

> Crossing the field, I did not know **but that** some one would fire on us from the trees near the farmhouse or from the farmhouse itself.

Comment: It's odd to me. I'd need more context to know what it means, which tells me it's not standard English today, if it ever was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an older, but common, usage, equivalent to "I [thought it possible, or likely,] that some one would fire on us." Or if you prefer double negatives, "I *didn't* know that *no one* would fire on us," which is perhaps closer to the original intent.

If you look in [Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=know%20but%20that&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cknow%20but%20that%3B%2Cc0) for "know but that," the peak occurrence of that usage was from ~1810 thought 1900, in their book *coprpus*. Its occurrence is increasing slightly, perhaps due to recent (re)publication of historical fiction.